# cordova-plugin-inapppurchase Cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova-plugin-inapppurchase with Ionic and I also opened an Issue on the plugin's repository: [Issue #78](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase/issues/78)

When I try to Restore a Purchase on iOS I get the Console Output below.
**Console output**

> RMStore: restored transactions failed with error Error
>   Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

The reviewer in the App Store wrote:

> Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network
>   (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and
>   resubmit your app for review.

Is the plugin IPv6 complaint? What is the issue otherwise, I have been stuck in this for several days now.

**Product Type**
Consumable

**Cordova version**
6.4.0

**iOS version**
iOS 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the account being related to another country. Nothing to do with the plugin.